# SQL query - Errors on column name but is not like that

Tags: sql

I am very new to this. I have created this table and I had no problems doing it:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Urban_Rail] (
[Id]      INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Country] VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[City]    VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[Type]    VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Gauge]   NCHAR (10)    NULL,
[Year]    NCHAR (10)    NULL,
[Status]  VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[Notes]   VARCHAR (500) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Now I am trying to fill in few thousand rows of data using this statement:

```
INSERT INTO Urban_Rail ('Id','Country','City','Type','Gauge','Year','Status','Notes') VALUES ('','Algeria','Algiers','Metro','1435','2011','Open','');
INSERT INTO Urban_Rail ('Id','Country','City','Type','Gauge','Year','Status','Notes') VALUES ('','Algeria','Algiers','Tram','1435','2011','Open','');
INSERT INTO Urban_Rail ('Id','Country','City','Type','Gauge','Year','Status','Notes') VALUES ('','Algeria','Batna','Tram','','','Planned','');
```

But I get errors saying that the name of each column is not valid. That does not look true to me. I am wondering if it has something to do with the Id instead which is an auto increment identity which I have left without value in my query. **What am I doing wrong here?** Some help will be appreciated.

Comment: Id is an identity column, remove it from your list of columns that you insert into.  It will automatically populate when you insert data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Should I remove it from both sides? I mean, like this: INSERT INTO Urban_Rail ('Country','City','Type','Gauge','Year','Status','Notes') VALUES ('Algeria','Algiers','Metro','1435','2011','Open','');

Comment: You should also not quote your column names with `'`, but with your database's way of quoting table and column names. In SQL Server it's usually `[]`.

Comment: Yes, remove it from both sides

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Yes, I didn't notice that either.  Since this appears to be sql server (square brackets) then the columns could be wrapped with brackets as well not single quotes

Comment: Use double quotes for identifiers, single quotes for string literals. For microsoft: you could use silly brackets for identifiers. For mysql: syou could use silly backticks.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson It worked with columns name in brackets [] and data in single quotes without the id. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either remove the ID from the Insert (as it is an Identity) or if you want specific ID's turn Identity_Insert on before running the insert and off again afterwards.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Urban_Rail] ON 

INSERT INTO Urban_Rail (Id,Country,City,Type,Gauge,Year,Status,Notes) VALUES (1,'Algeria','Algiers','Metro','1435','2011','Open','');

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Urban_Rail] OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

An IDENTITY column should not be included in the INSERT statement.  It will automatically populate with the next value.

Answer (score 0):

The column "ID" is an identity column and you're not allowed to insert it since the database assigns it. Take it off the column name and values list in your inserts.

If you DO need to insert the identity column, you can use

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT <table> ON
```

But am guessing you don't need that since your ID's look blank.